# VBA : Showed wrong date format

Tags: excel, vba

I`ve vba code to display date in a specific format like below

```
If Not IsNull(Data.getAttribute("recorded"))) Then
    Range("BG3") = Format((Data.getAttribute("recorded")), "dd / mmm / yyyy")
End If
```

This code actually works in my local. But in server it showed format as '02.14.2013'.

Due to wrong date format I went in some problem.

What might be the cause for this?
Someone please help me.

Comment: What should it look like?
Is the "mmm" correct? It looks unusual

Comment: Different Regional Setting? `/` vs `.`

Comment: Can you put this in context. Where is the result of Format((Data.getAt.... being used? Are you displaying it in a cell? If so please provide the line of code that does this. Also have you stepped through the code to see if perhaps it is initially displaying in the correct format but maybe you are resetting the format later on?

Comment: @Dan: This is happening in some server that I dont exactly know. But resetting should affect to other date filled cells too,it`s not happening like.It`s screwed only to this cell(BG3).

Comment: @SiddharthRout: What you mean? my code will change depending upon Regional settings???

Comment: @user2002774 Should that not be Range("BG3").Value2 = Format.... try that? Are you doing anything else in that code later on to a range that include BG3?

Comment: @Dan: No i`m not doing anything wit cell later. My code is enough to work it correctly.

Comment: Are you displaying this in excel on the server or importing on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try and add the following before the `Range` statement:

```
Range("BG3").NumberFormat = "@" 'set to display as text
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try:

```
If Not IsNull(Data.getAttribute("recorded"))) Then
    Range("BG3").Value2 = Format((Data.getAttribute("recorded")), "dd / mmm / yyyy")
End If
```

And if that is still a problem

```
If Not IsNull(Data.getAttribute("recorded"))) Then
    Range("BG3").Value = Data.getAttribute("recorded")
    Range("BG3").NumberFormat = "dd / mmm / yyyy"
End If
```

But I still stand by putting a break point somewhere strategic and stepping through the code to make certain the the number appears in the cell in the incorrect format as opposed to being reset later on.